# How to get asset ids claimed in specific video via YouTube Partner API?

Tags: youtube-api

Given specific video id (not owned by me), how can i get list of assets claimed in that video? I can do that via https://cms.youtube.com/manual_claim, but is there a way to do this via youtube partner api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check other people's ownership or management rights on a video or channel. YouTube deliberately avoids that. There is [claimSearch->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claimSearch/list) method in Partner API but with that you can only search "your" claims.